# Flink's Quickstart doesn't create a proper fat-jar

Tags: maven, apache-flink

i'm definitely not an expert in mvn, but after 2 days hacking around, i'm just giving up.

my workflow:

```
1.     
     mvn archetype:generate                             
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink            
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-scala   
    -DarchetypeVersion=0.10.1                       
    -DgroupId=org.apache.flink.quickstart          
    -DartifactId=flink-scala-project               
    -Dversion=0.1                                  
    -Dpackage=org.apache.flink.quickstart          
    -DinteractiveMode=false    

2.    
   cd flink-scala-project 

3.     
  mvn clean package
```

here is a build `log: https://gist.github.com/zavalit/1e78478ebdda827f3454` and when I run

```
`java -jar target/flink-scala-project-0.1.jar`
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/scala/ExecutionEnvironment$
    at org.apache.flink.quickstart.Job$.main(Job.scala:41)
    at org.apache.flink.quickstart.Job.main(Job.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 8):

The fat jar which you're building is not supposed to be run outside of a cluster environment. Therefore, all Flink related dependencies which run in the cluster environment are excluded from the fat jar.

What you usually do with the generated fat jar is to submit it to a local or remote cluster via `bin/flink run -c org.example.MyJob myFatJar.jar`. In order to start quickly a local cluster you can run `bin/start-local.sh`. This will start a local cluster to which you can submit your job jar.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the flink libraries are not included in the fat jar since it would be provided by flink cluster at runtime. To fix that, change the `scope` of dependencies in `pom.xml`, from `provided` to `compile`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

link: [Maven Doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)